# How to convert one of my columns from 226 FACTORS?

Tags: r, dataframe

New to programming in R. I have a dataset in which one column is or should be numeric since it has %values! I need to plot that data using ggplot2 but I can't since I'm pretty new with this.

Summary:
DataSet = 245 Rows, 6 columns.

I have spent  5 hours searching for the right code. But posts seem to be to advance for my understanding.

```
data.frame':    245 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ location : Factor w/ 8 levels "site01","site02",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ coralType: Factor w/ 5 levels "blue corals",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ longitude: num  144 144 144 144 144 ...
 $ latitude : num  -11.8 -11.8 -11.8 -11.8 -11.8 ...
 $ year     : int  2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2011 2012 ...
 $ value    : Factor w/ 223 levels "10.01%","10.23%",..: 113 123 166 168 184 193 196 200 43 44 ...
```

See that `df$value`? That is my issue I need it to be numeric so I can plot it, right now I can't! Simply put $value needs to be numeric. Would really appreciate if any of you R veterans can help me out?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the percentage symbol and save it as a numeric value.

```
df <- data.frame(value = paste(1:100, "%", sep = ""))
df$value <- as.numeric(sub("%", "", df$value))
```

Comment: When you load your data, for example, when you read it from a csv file, try adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to the call and then it won't make your character data factor by default. Factors cause TONS of problems when you don't realize they're there.